# How to fix UIButton not responding to touch?

Tags: swift, uibutton, addtarget

I am working an app with quizzes, have 4 UIButtons (custom type) on subview which is custom view and none of the buttons is recognising the action even though I set the target. I have to do it programatically.

I have tried setting isUserInteractionEnabled but it is not working. Buttons are on the view, respecting the bounds.

Here, `viewDidLoad` from `InitialViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() 

{

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.questionView?.firstanswer!.isEnabled = true

    self.questionView?.firstanswer!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.answerTheQuestion), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    self.questionView?.secondanswer!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.answerTheQuestion), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    self.questionView?.thirdanswer!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.answerTheQuestion), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

    self.questionView?.fourthanswer!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.answerTheQuestion), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)

}
```

Here is the action function:

```
@objc func answerTheQuestion(_sender:UIButton) {

   print("aa")

   if let questionsAnswers = self.quizzes?.quizzes[self.randomNumber!]["questions"] as?  [[String:Any]] {

    if (questionsAnswers[self.randomQuestion!]["question"] as? String) != nil { 

       if let correctAnswer = questionsAnswers[self.randomQuestion!]["correct_answer"] as? String {
           if _sender.titleLabel?.text == correctAnswer {
              _sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
           } else {
            _sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           }
       }
    }
  } 
}
```

View and buttons are added normally, only tap is not working.

It should go red when the answer is wrong, and green when it is right. Questions and everything else is added normally, but it even won't print "aaa" in the beginning of the target function. Pls help, thanks!!

Comment: Can we have a screenshot of the debug view hierarchy?

Comment: Is `questionView` nil during `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: @Don No it is not. It normally looks on the screen with buttons and labels and everything

Comment: @Fallah There is InitialViewController with subview QuestionView (which is custom view) and UIButtons which are subviews of questionview.

Comment: Is userInteractionEnabled true for questionView?

Comment: Also, if your function is `func answerTheQuestion(_ sender: UIButton)`, your #selector should be `#selector(answerTheQuestion(_:))`. If it is `func answerTheQuestion(sender: UIButton)` it should be `#selector(answerTheQuestion(sender:))`

Comment: If you have not found a solution please attach the .xcodeproj